# How to encode character in Microsoft Windows Codepage 1251 (Cyrl) in java

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I want to encode string in Java with Microsoft Windows Codepage 1251 (Cyrl) table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to "encode" a string. When you turn a string from/to bytes you need to decode/encode them. So you actually encode a binary array.

```
byte[] cp1251encodedBytes = "your characters".getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp1251"));
```

List of supported encodings: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html

Update: updated to Charset.forName() as McDowell commented.

Comment: you can use the `Charset` type to avoid having to deal with checked exceptions

Comment: I get: The method getBytes(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Charset)

Comment: @Gogoo @Peter Knego - ah, my mistake - the `String(Charset)` constructor wasn't introduced until Java 6. Using the string version Peter originally proposed should do the trick.